# How can I conditionally choose types depending on whether a property exists in another type?

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

First off, I want the following result:

```
type Wrapper<ID extends string> = { id: ID };
type WrapperWithPayload<ID extends string, Payload> = { id: ID, payload: Payload };

enum IDs {
  FOO = "ID Foo",
  BAR = "ID Bar",
  BAZ = "ID Baz"
}

interface AssociatedTypes {
  [IDs.FOO]: number;
  [IDs.BAR]: number[];
}

type Result = MagicMapper<IDs, AssociatedTypes>
/*
 * Result should have this type:
 * {
 *   [IDs.FOO]: WrapperWithPayload<IDs.FOO, number>;
 *   [IDs.BAR]: WrapperWithPayload<IDs.BAR, number[]>;
 *   [IDs.BAZ]: Wrapper<IDs.BAZ>;
 * }
 */
```

In other words, I want to supply some strings and a mapping, which maps a subset of those strings to another type. Then, I want to create a new type using the strings as keys. For each of the strings/keys, if a mapping exists, I want to use type A, and otherwise I want to use type B.

Right now, my approach looks like this:

```
type MagicMapper<T extends string, Mapping extends { [key in T]?: any }> = {
    [key in T]: Mapping[key] extends never ? Wrapper<key> : WrapperWithPayload<key, Mapping[key]>;
};
```

And that one almost hits the goal:

```
type Result = {
  "ID Foo": WrapperWithPayload<IDs.FOO, number>;
  "ID Bar": WrapperWithPayload<IDs.BAR, number[]>;
  "ID Baz": Wrapper<IDs.BAZ> | WrapperWithPayload<IDs.BAZ, any>;
}
```

The union on the Baz key is wrong. I think the error lies within the `extends never` condition, but replacing it with, e.g., undefined makes things only worse:

```
type MagicMapper<T extends string, Mapping extends { [key in T]?: any }> = {
    [key in T]: Mapping[key] extends undefined ? Wrapper<key> : WrapperWithPayload<key, Mapping[key]>;
};

type Result = {
  "ID Foo": Wrapper<IDs.FOO>;
  "ID Bar": Wrapper<IDs.BAR>;
  "ID Baz": Wrapper<IDs.BAZ>;
}
```

Is there any way to make things work the way I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the test for the existence of the key in `Mapping` to `Mapping extends { [P in key]: infer U }` and everything will work as expected:

```
type Wrapper<ID extends string> = { id: ID };
type WrapperWithPayload<ID extends string, Payload> = { id: ID, payload: Payload };

enum IDs {
    FOO = "ID Foo",
    BAR = "ID Bar",
    BAZ = "ID Baz"
}

interface AssociatedTypes {
    [IDs.FOO]: number;
    [IDs.BAR]: number[];
}

type MagicMapper<T extends string, Mapping extends { [key in T]?: any }> = {
    [key in T]: Mapping extends { [P in key]: infer U } ? WrapperWithPayload<key, U>: Wrapper<key> ;
};
type Result = MagicMapper<IDs, AssociatedTypes> 
// same as :
type Result = {
    "ID Foo": WrapperWithPayload<IDs.FOO, number>;
    "ID Bar": WrapperWithPayload<IDs.BAR, number[]>;
    "ID Baz": Wrapper<IDs.BAZ>;
}
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Wrapper%3CID%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20id%3A%20ID%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20WrapperWithPayload%3CID%20extends%20string%2C%20Payload%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20id%3A%20ID%2C%20payload%3A%20Payload%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20IDs%20%7B%0D%0AFOO%20%3D%20%22ID%20Foo%22%2C%0D%0ABAR%20%3D%20%22ID%20Bar%22%2C%0D%0ABAZ%20%3D%20%22ID%20Baz%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20AssociatedTypes%20%7B%0D%0A%5BIDs.FOO%5D%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%5BIDs.BAR%5D%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20MagicMapper%3CT%20extends%20string%2C%20Mapping%20extends%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20T%5D%3F%3A%20any%20%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%20in%20T%5D%3A%20Mapping%20extends%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20key%5D%3A%20infer%20U%20%7D%20%3F%20WrapperWithPayload%3Ckey%2C%20U%3E%3A%20Wrapper%3Ckey%3E%20%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Result%20%3D%20MagicMapper%3CIDs%2C%20AssociatedTypes%3E%20%0D%0A)

Comment: Thanks! Using `infer` didn't come to my mind, mainly because I'm still unsure what exactly it does. I actually came up with a different approach right now which seems to achieve the same result so far, by using `[key in T]: key extends keyof Mapping ? WrapperWithPayload<key, Mapping[key]> : Wrapper<key>` and changing the base type of mapping to `{ [key: string]: any }`. I'll mark your answer as solving, just wanted to show that more than one way leads to the goal, as is often the case.

Comment: @Nimelrian Yeah, that looks like a good way too, I go to conditional types to quickly these days :)